# Get all images from FirebaseStorage in Numerical Order

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a folder named "Notes" in my Firebase Storage and have images in it named from 1-10.

1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg....

I want to get their Image Download URL and want to display it in my viewpager.

Currently i use this code.

```
 final StorageReference okref = mStorageRef.child("Notes/");

        okref.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                    item.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            String URI = uri.toString();
                            arrayList.add(URI);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Taks copmpleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                }
  }
        });
```

But using this I get images in random order.I want the order to be 1.jpg then 2.jpg then 3.jpg...in my viewpager

I am using viewpager for ImageSlider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDownloadUrl()` is asynchronous and doesn't give you a guarantee in what order it will generate a result compared to other asynchronous calls to `getDownloadUrl()`.  If you need an order to the results, you will have to write code to make sure the results have the order that you expect.  You could do this by iterating with a `for` loop with an integer index, and populating your array with that index.  The general form of this solution might go like this (this is psuedocode and will not compile):

```
items = listResult.getItems();
for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
    item = items[i];
    item.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            String URI = uri.toString();
            arrayList.set(i, URI);
        }
    });    
}
```

See that the integer index is used consistently to decide which element is being worked with.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier with the concat map operator?

Comment: @AdityaKurkure I don't know, would it? If you have an answer, feel free to share it here.